# PHP open file on server with get variables?

Tags: php

Okay, basically, I have a PHP script written all up (it's an MMORPG, so we're clear).

What I'd love to be able to do is rather than writing new (massive) files that contain the exact same data, just in one big script (so as to be able to create more of an NPC aspect to the game), I'd rather just be able to send a request to open page.php using predefined get variables (i.e., collect=Y or attack=Y etc) that would be virtually identical to how a real player send the requests, and have the system open the file, run through the file, and make whatever queries to the database it needs to before closing it.

I'm confused on how fopen works to be honest, some things I've read make me believe the above is possible, others not so much.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `file_get_contents('http://fullurl.to/file.php?collect=y&attack=y');`

Comment: I'm not entirely clear on what you're trying to do, but have you made your script into a class or an object with public methods that you can call?

Comment: It is rare that you have to use `fopen()`. Most of the time you should use something like `file_get_contents()` and `file_put_contents()`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to go out on a limb, here, and try to solve your problem (as I understand it) rather than answer your question (as you have cast it).

Your fundamental problem is that you have treated PHP files as complete units of code, with input from the query string, processing specific to that file, and output back to the user. This violates the "single responsibility principle", because there are at least three top-level responsibilities here:

- Processing user input and deciding on the appropriate action
- Performing an action, including manipulation of database structures
- Communicating the result of an action back to the user

These can all be broken down into smaller tasks - for instance, the nitty-gritty of connecting to the database should kept out of the more abstract actions, because changing how an enemy moves, and changing that enemy to be stored in a MongoDB document rather than a MySQL table should not require changes to the same code.

The solution, therefore, is to embrace structured programming, which in modern PHP (and many other languages) usually means embracing object-oriented programming. So, at a first level of organisation, you might have:

- A class for looking at the query string, checking that it makes sense, and creating an abstract list of actions described by it.
- Classes representing certain actions such as "Attack" and "Collect", which take details of what is being attacked or collected from the abstract list, and return a different abstract list detailing the results.
- Classes representing the player, and enemies or objects within the game, which can be used by the action classes to calculate the outcome in different situations.
- Classes for taking the result of actions and displaying them to the user.

Now, instead of saying "I need to create a query string, run the code the page would run, then take the output and use it somehow" you can say "I need to create an action list, run the appropriate actions, and use the result list somehow".

It may sound like that's a lot more work than just forcing PHP to run the existing code, but the power it gives you to create new combinations of existing functionality is not to be under-estimated.